# Is there a way to see dictionary like an enumerate list in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

the question might be not clear enough of what I'm trying to figure out so here are the details.

For instance, if I have a list that looks something like this
{'a': 1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4}

How can I see it like as below?

a: 1

b: 2

c: 3

d: 4

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is a dict obviously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for k, v in d.items(): 
    print(k,':', v)
```